# How to avoid duplication while trying to display employee work details consisting of start & end dates, hours worked and hourly rate in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the table I have created and inserted values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE employees_list   
(
    employeeID int identity(1,1),   
    employeeName varchar(25)
)  
GO   
  
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES ('Kevin'),('Charles')  
GO   
   
CREATE TABLE hourlyRates   
(
    employeeID int,   
    rate int,   
    rateDate date
)   
  
INSERT INTO hourlyRates VALUES (1, 28, '2016-01-01'),   
                               (1, 39, '2016-02-01'),  
                               (2, 43, '2016-01-01'),  
                               (2, 57, '2016-02-01')  
  
  
CREATE TABLE workingHours   
( 
    employeeID int,   
    startdate datetime,   
    enddate datetime
)  
GO   
  
INSERT INTO workingHours VALUES (1, '2016-01-01 09:00', '2016-01-01 17:00'),  
                                (1, '2016-01-02 09:00', '2016-01-02 17:00'),  
                                (1, '2016-02-01 10:00', '2016-02-01 16:00'),  
                                (1, '2016-02-02 11:00', '2016-02-02 13:00'),  
                                (2, '2016-01-01 10:00', '2016-01-01 16:00'),  
                                (2, '2016-01-02 08:00', '2016-01-02 14:00'),  
                                (2, '2016-02-01 14:00', '2016-02-01 19:00'),  
                                (2, '2016-02-02 13:00', '2016-02-02 16:00')  
GO

SELECT * FROM employees_list
SELECT * FROM hourlyRates
SELECT * FROM workingHours
```

Now the question is:

Display employee ID, name, start date, end date, hours worked and hourly rate for the Employee whose ID number is 1.

This is what I have done:

```
SELECT 
    workingHours.employeeID, employeeName,
    startdate, enddate,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, startdate, enddate) AS 'Hours Worked',
    rate AS 'Hourly Rate'
FROM 
    hourlyRates, workingHours, employees_list
WHERE 
    hourlyRates.employeeID = workingHours.employeeID
    AND employees_list.employeeID = workingHours.employeeID
    AND workingHours.employeeID = 1
```

And I got the following result:

[image]

The problem with the result above is that the result is being repeated or duplicated from row number 5 to row number 8.
It is supposed to generate the first 4 rows if I'm not mistaken.

I even tried adding DISTINCT in the SELECT statement and still it is showing duplicated result.

What change is needed on my query to eliminate the duplication?

Comment: It is not a duplicate if you see. When you join `hourlyRates` with `workingHours` you will get 8 results. 2 from `workingHours` and 4 from `workingHours` if joined you will get 8 different results. Your hourly rate is different when you think your `startdate` is duplicated.

Comment: `FROM hourlyRates,workingHours,employees_list` Nope - start over. No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). There are good habits you SHOULD be using as well - schema-qualified names, short but not cryptic aliases, using alias with every column reference, etc. And stop cramming your code together. Readability is **important**

Comment: I think when you inserted the data itself, it went wrong. How can someone work 2 times on the same day if that's not the logic you intended?

Comment: How are you applying the "RateDate", i.e. is it meant to be an effective date?

Comment: @SanishJoseph - The working dates are unique, but as you pointed out, the hourly rates are not, giving the "impression" of duplicate rows.

Comment: @SOS yes those are unique. My bad. I hope if `rateDate` is related to start/endDate, things would have been easier.

Comment: @SanishJoseph - Yeah, I was thinking it'd be easier if "RateDate" were instead a range "RateStartDate" and "RateEndDate".  Because it's not clear whether a "RateDate" of 2016-01-01 is supposed to mean "This is the rate for January 2016" or ... "This is the rate from now until a later date is entered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're joining the tables only on the `employeeID`. With that, you will get a row for every combination of `hourlyRates` and `workingHours` - which is 8 in this case. You'd have to join the tables somehow on the dates as well. You want to take a rate from `hourlyRates` only when it's in the correct month. The simplest way to do that with your query would be adding another join condition:

```
SELECT workingHours.employeeID,employeeName,startdate,enddate,
DATEDIFF(HOUR,startdate,enddate) AS 'Hours Worked',
rate AS 'Hourly Rate'
FROM hourlyRates,workingHours,employees_list
WHERE hourlyRates.employeeID = workingHours.employeeID
AND employees_list.employeeID = workingHours.employeeID
AND (hourlyRates.rateDate
    BETWEEN 
    DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, workingHours.startDate), DATEPART(MONTH,workingHours.startDate), 1) 
    AND DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, workingHours.endDate), DATEPART(MONTH,workingHours.endDate), 1)) 
AND workingHours.employeeID = 1
```

The new join condition is taking year and month parts with the [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function, from `workingHours`'s dates, and making sure that `hourlyRates.rateDate` is between those two.

[DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function takes year, month and day integers (for the start of the month, we take that day is 1) and converts it to `DATE` type.

---

There are a couple of problems with the above query however. The obvious one being the syntax. You should use the [new join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). The other problem is that the query is not [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) because of the function calls on column values in the join condition. These queries should be avoided when possible.

There are a [couple of ways](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/) of making a query sargable. For example we could insert the processed dates into a [temp table](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-and-performance-tips-of-temp-tables-in-sql-server/), and use it for the query:

```
SELECT wh.employeeID
    ,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, wh.startDate), DATEPART(MONTH,wh.startDate), 1) AS startDateYearMonth
    ,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, wh.endDate), DATEPART(MONTH,wh.endDate), 1) AS endDateMonthYearMonth
    ,wh.startdate
    ,wh.enddate
INTO #TempWorkingHours
FROM workingHours wh

SELECT el.employeeID
       ,el.employeeName
       ,twh.startdate
       ,twh.enddate
       ,DATEDIFF(HOUR,twh.startdate,twh.enddate) AS [Hours Worked]
       ,hr.rate AS [Hourly Rate]
FROM employees_list el 
    JOIN hourlyRates hr ON el.employeeID = hr.employeeID
    JOIN #TempWorkingHours twh ON el.employeeID = twh.employeeID
        AND (hr.rateDate
            BETWEEN 
            twh.startDateYearMonth 
            AND twh.endDateMonthYearMonth
        ) 
WHERE el.employeeID = 1
```

Note that this will not improve performance (will even make it worse because of the temp table overhead) if you don't use [indexes on the pre-processed columns](https://www.sqlshack.com/indexing-sql-server-temporary-tables/). Without indexes, a non-sargable query will be fine, and with the new join syntax would look like this:

```
SELECT el.employeeID
       ,el.employeeName
       ,wh.startdate
       ,wh.enddate
       ,DATEDIFF(HOUR,wh.startdate,wh.enddate) AS [Hours Worked]
       ,hr.rate AS [Hourly Rate]
FROM employees_list el 
    JOIN hourlyRates hr ON el.employeeID = hr.employeeID
    JOIN workingHours wh ON hr.employeeID = wh.EmployeeID 
        AND (hr.rateDate
            BETWEEN 
            DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, wh.startDate), DATEPART(MONTH,wh.startDate), 1) 
            AND DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, wh.endDate), DATEPART(MONTH,wh.endDate), 1)
        ) 
WHERE wh.employeeID = 1
```

Comment: It would be better if the query were [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) :-)

Comment: @pro_data - If you're learning sql, you should also read about sargable queries: " ...In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of an index **to speed up the execution of the query.**". You should avoid *non*-sargable queries whenever possible.  https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/non-sargable-predicates/

Comment: @PajLe .... Your query perfectly worked. 

I have marked your answer as accepted.

Just 2 questions.

 What does DATEFROMPARTS do ?
 and What does ,1 (inside the DATEFROMPARTS) mean ?

Comment: @pro_data `DATEFROMPARTS` takes in 3 parts (year, month, day) and combines them into a `DATE` type. Since we only want the years and months, we can put the day to be 1.

@SOS Thanks! Looking into making a sargeable one

Comment: @PajLe -- 
In this case,(related to the query)
Does the day always needs to be 1 ?
OR it can be any other number besides 1 ?

Comment: Since `rateDate`'s day is 1, it wouldn't be included in a month if you would put the `startdate`'s day from 2. For example: `rateDate` is 2016-01-01, `startDate` is 2016-01-05, `endDate` is 2016-01-31, `rateDate` won't be between those two